# How to add more than 1 range to a windows.selection object in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, range, selection, copy-paste

I want to implement the copy and paste feature in my web page.
I would like to use document.execcommand("copy") to implement the feature,so that user can use Ctrl-Z to roll back the copy action.

The following code working prorperly in firefox browser, it can add more than 1 range to window.selection object.
However, it can add only 1 range to window.selection in Chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Copy event to clipboard</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("body").on("copy",copy);
      });
      function copy(event)
      {
        var cell1,cell2;
        var endCol=getValue("endCol");
        var endRow=getValue("endRow");
        var range;
        var startCol=getValue("startCol"),startRow=getValue("startRow");
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        for (var i=startRow;i<=endRow;i++)
        {
          range = document.createRange();
          cell1=getCell(i,startCol);
          cell2=getCell(i,endCol);
          range.setStart(cell1,0);
          range.setEnd(cell2,cell2.childNodes.length);
          selection.addRange(range);
        }
      }
      function copyContent()
      {
        document.execCommand("copy");
      }
      function getCell(rowIndex,cellIndex)
      {
        var table=document.getElementById("dataTable");
        var row=table.rows[rowIndex];
        var cell=row.cells[cellIndex];
        return cell;
      }
      function getValue(id)
      {
        var element=document.getElementById(id);
        var index=element.selectedIndex;
        return element.options[index].value;
      }
    </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" id="dataTable">
      <tr>
        <td id="c11" contenteditable="true">1_1</td>
        <td id="c12" contenteditable="true">1_2</td>
        <td id="c13" contenteditable="true">1_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="c21" contenteditable="true">2_1</td>
        <td id="c22" contenteditable="true">2_2</td>
        <td id="c23" contenteditable="true">2_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="c31" contenteditable="true">3_1</td>
        <td id="c32" contenteditable="true">3_2</td>
        <td id="c33" contenteditable="true">3_3</td>
      </tr>
    </table><br>
    start column:
    <select id="startCol">
      <option value=0>1</option>
      <option value=1>2</option>
      <option value=2>3</option>
    </select>
    end column:
    <select id="endCol">
      <option value=0>1</option>
      <option value=1>2</option>
      <option value=2>3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    start row:
    <select id="startRow">
      <option value=0>1</option>
      <option value=1>2</option>
      <option value=2>3</option>
    </select>
    end row:
    <select id="endRow">
      <option value=0>1</option>
      <option value=1>2</option>
      <option value=2>3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="copyContent()">Copy</button>
    <textarea id=copiedContent>
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any work around so that I can add more than 1 range to window.selection object in Chrome browser?

Comment: Not really, actually it's even been removed from specs. This is an old relic from Netscape that FF did keep and which made the Selection API have things like rangeCount or removeAllRanges(), but this behavior is non-standard. To do what you wish, you'd have to keep yourself track of what the selected cells were, and to merge their content in a single hidden Node that you'll use as the source for `execCommand('copy')`. That's a bit of work though...