# Simulate an user input through the keyboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I know this question has been asked for so many times.

I have tried the following solutions:

[My Testing 1](https://jsfiddle.net/03ex76u5/)

[My Testing 2](https://jsfiddle.net/03ex76u5/2/)

[My Testing 3](https://jsfiddle.net/03ex76u5/3/)

[My Testing 4](https://jsfiddle.net/ekwtf2sp/)

Here is the fifth solutions:

```js
var keyEvents = ['keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress'];
var noIdeaEvents = ["focus", "focusin", "mousemove", "hover", "mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click", "dblclick", "change", "mouseleave", "mouseout", "mouseenter", "blur", "focusout", "select", "pointermove", "pointerover", "pointerdown", "pointerup", "pointerout", "keydown", "keyup", "keypress", "input"];

function raiseEvents(target, eventsArr, k) {
  var events = eventsArr;

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    try {
      if (window.dispatchEvent) {
        if (events[i].indexOf("mouse") >= 0) {
          var eventObject = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
          eventObject.initMouseEvent(events[i], true, true, window, 0, eventObject.screenX, eventObject.screenY, eventObject.clientX, eventObject.clientY, eventObject.ctrlKey, eventObject.altKey, eventObject.shiftKey, eventObject.metaKey, 0, null);
          console.log(events[i] + ": initialized as MouseEvents.");
        } else if (window.PointerEvent && events[i].indexOf("pointer") >= 0) {
          var eventObject = document.createEvent("PointerEvent");
          eventObject.initPointerEvent(events[i], true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, "mouse", 0, 0);
          //var eventObject = new PointerEvent(events[i], { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, composed: true, pointerId: 42, pointerType: "mouse", clientX: 0, clientY: 0 });
          console.log(events[i] + ": initialized as PointerEvent");
        } else if (events[i].indexOf("blur") >= 0 || events[i].indexOf("focus") >= 0) {
          var eventObject = document.createEvent("FocusEvent");
          eventObject.initEvent(events[i], true, false);
          console.log(events[i] + ": initialized as FocusEvent");
        } else if (window.KeyboardEvent && events[i].indexOf("key") >= 0) {
          var eventObject = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
          eventObject.initKeyboardEvent(events[i], true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, k);
          console.log(events[i] + ": initialized as KeyboardEvent");
        } else {
          var eventObject = document.createEvent("Event");
          eventObject.initEvent(events[i], true, false);
          console.log(events[i] + ": initialized as Event");
        }
        target.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
        console.log(events[i] + ": dispatch complete");
      } else {
        var eventObject = document.createEventObject();
        console.log("EventObject is initialized (IE8)");
        eventObject.button = 1;
        target.fireEvent("on" + events[i], eventObject);
        console.log("on" + events[i] + ": fire complete");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(events[i] + ": " + err.message);
    }
  }
}

function go() {
  var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
  console.log(inputBox);
  raiseEvents(inputBox, noIdeaEvents, 65);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputBox"></textarea>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

However, none of them is working in Chrome and Firefox browser.

That mean none of the above solution can put the character "a" to the input text box.

Why these solutions are not working?

Is there any trick to make it work?

Comment: I think you are completely on the wrong track. If you want to put a character into the textarea, just assign it as the value: `document.getElementById('inputBox').value = 'a';`. The textarea doesn't have any listeners, so it will not respond to any events.

Comment: I want to implement the copy and paste feature in my web page. I would like to use document.execcommand("copy") to implement the feature,so that user can use Ctrl-Z to roll back the copy action. However, the Google Chrome browser seem to be not support multiple range in a selection, therefore, I need to find another solution for this problem. You may refere my [previous post][1].



[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529346/how-can-i-copy-more-than-1-table-cell-data-and-then-paste-the-data-to-the-destin

Comment: Why are you replicating (and possibly breaking) default UI behaviour? People become used to how the applications they use behave. When you reprogram that behaviour so that it doesn't work as they expect, it's very, very annoying.

Comment: The problem I facing is I cannot paste the copied value to my table cells(those cells are set contenteditable=true).
If I can simulate the keypress, then the undo function can be done by the browser.

Comment: @pete
The solution does not work.

Comment: Even if you were able to simulate those key presses, the default behavior of Paste would not apply. Why can't you set the content of your table's cells? That's where we should help you rather than in this horrible hack. (Just think about what it would mean for a device that has no keyboard, like a phone, and even every user may have their own key-map for different OS operations, on my computer, ctrl+v does scroll to next page in a textarea, like Page Down button would, it doesn't paste anything)

Comment: I have tried to set the value to the table cell, but the undo function(i.e. Ctrl-z) does not work anymore.